# Apigee PUSH | Exclude notification generator from becoming a notification receiver

Tags: android, notifications, apigee

I have got the Apigee Android push notification to work. But I have a final hurdle to cross. I am using the JS SDK to generate notifications.

Since the end point is **devices;ql=*/notifications** expectedly the notification is being delivered to the device that generated it!

```
    var options = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    endpoint: 'devices;ql=*/notifications',
                    body: {
                        'payloads': {
                            'notifier': {
                                'message': message,
                                'title': title,
                                'msgcnt': '1'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

                client.request(options, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        //error - POST failed
                    } else {
                        //data will contain raw results from API call
                        //success - POST worked
                    }
                });
```

How do I exclude the device that generate the notification?

Answer (score 0):

This query you're using specifically gets every device. You can exclude a specific device with the NOT operator:

?ql=NOT uuid='e15a1924-0c76-11e4-bc79-c76eb28f1666'

One issue is that I think you'll be limited to the number of devices returned by the query (10 by default), so you'll want to add a LIMIT to get all devices:

?ql=NOT uuid='e15a1924-0c76-11e4-bc79-c76eb28f1666'&limit=1000

The max you can request is 1000, so keep in mind that paging may be necessary.

Comment: that wont work  GET on https://api.usergrid.com/org/app/referrals?ql=NOT uuid="66a8c62a-940d-11e4-a427-9deac733b760" 
throws 
org.apache.usergrid.persistence.exceptions.QueryTokenException NoViableAltException

Comment: Depending on how you're making the request, you will need to escape the spaces and single quotes (I think this would apply to both curl and Android SDK):

?ql=NOT%20uuid=%27a6dbe22a-8ec0-11e3-89da-25a0e8d80900%27

I've also tested this syntax in Postman without a problem.